# Line breaks inside commands

Tags: line-breaking

Is there a way to have line breaks inside commands that don't accept line breaks. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \mbox{line 1\\line 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the problem with ``\texttt{line 1\\line2}``? `\texttt` accepts line breaks.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question...

Comment: I think he asked a general question about control sequences that do not allow for vertical mode.  Along the lines of "How do I allow for multiple lines using this?", but gave an example of a control sequence that does allow for multiple lines/vertical mode. At least that's the best of my understanding of it.

Comment: @AFeldman Yes, that's correct. For some reason, when I used the standalone class the `\texttt{a\\b} didn't work. I fixed this to another example.

Answer (score 8):

Some examples and solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\texttt{line 1\\line 2}

\emph{line 1\\line 2}

But:

\mbox{line 1\\line 2}

\fbox{line 1\\line2}

Solutions:

\fbox{\parbox{5cm}{line 1\\line 2}} % or environment minipage

% varwidth is like minipage, but truncates the lines if possible:
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{5cm}line 1\\line 2\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ll}line 1\\line 2\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nice answer, even though the question was perhaps questionable.

Answer (score 3):

By putting it into a box that allows line breaks.  For instance like a `\vbox`, you could also use a `\vtop` box to allow for this.  The problem is that you need to get out of horizontal mode where a normal `\hbox` only allows single lines up to `\hsize` in width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

        \mbox{\vbox{\noindent line1\\line2}}

 \end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

but, as Werner pointed out, using `\texttt` there is no need to use anything because it does allow paragraphs.

But, using a `\fbox`, a command which does not allow for multiple paragraphs (thanks to Heiko Oberdiek for his below examples):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \fbox{\vbox{\noindent line 1\\line 2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result if you use a `\vtop` box:

```
    \fbox{\vtop{\noindent line 1\\line 2}}
```

[image]

Comment: `\texttt` accepts an argument. In your case you're only supplying the first token `l` (which is evident from your output). Also, `\texttt` accepts line breaks, so there's no need for `\vbox`.

Comment: `\texttt` changes the fonts using in the document.